# El emulador de android studio no funciona ni con la platilla preterminada de "Hello World"

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Al Iniciar me ejecuta el gradle y no detecta ningún error posterior sale estos al iniciar el emulador:

> 21:58 Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot
>   find certfile: C:\Users\Lenovo.android\emulator-grpc.cer security
>   will be disabled.
>
> 21:58 Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instala la app en el emulador y crashea y dice que se a detenido.

y sale esto:

> 22:00 Emulator: dsound: warning: Voice is not capturing

Ya intente instalado otros emuladores con versiones anteriores , restaurar y borrar el cache , hacer inicio en frío y instalar la app de nuevo.

Sigue sin funcionar antes de la actualización funcionaba perfectamente. ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Que tal? aunque lo que te sale es un aviso (no un error) todo nos indica que le pegaste a un bug del emulador propio /tal y como lo indica en JIRA [1](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-9120); no se que version de JDK estes utilizando, pero lo mas cercano a Java 8 (De Oracle u Open JDK) podria ayudar.

Si logras reproducir el error y adjuntar un pantallazo quiza pueda ayudarte un poco mas, por favor incluye:

- Version de Java usada
- Si la variable PATH y JAVA_HOME han sido correctamente puestas
- Algo quiza tonto, pero, nunca esta de mes, verificar que no corres una version de 32 bits sobre una de 64.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer]

Comment: El OP está utilizando Android Studio. En que sentido es relevante un enlace a un bug de Appcelerator? Por otro lado, la zona de respuestas no es la indicada para solicitar mas información al autor de la pregunta.

Comment: ya agregue las fotos, aparte ahora probe el emulador utilizando flutter el pluggin y me funciona no se cierra ni crashea , si me podrian ayudar o explicar porque salta el error pero si ejecuta mi codigo en flutter